# Is it possible to have a one-to-many relation in EF7 between two generic classes?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-7.0

I have a class called GatewayClaims and a class called GatewayItems. And yes, the project I'm working on is a gateway.
I have several classes derived from GatewayItems: GatewayUser, GatewayCompany, GatewayRole and a few more. Each of these derived classes will hold claims. (Actually, just values. Simplified here.) And these claims gets passed forward to another service as a JWT token. This should work just fine.
But the problem is this:

```
public class GatewayClaim
{
    public GatewayItem Item { get; set; } = new();
}
public abstract class GatewayItem 
{
    public List<GatewayClaim> Claims { get; set; } = new();
}
```

The "abstract" is part of the challenge here...
The problem is that I want separate tables for each item/claim pair so I have UserItems/UserClaims, CompanyItems/CompanyClaims, etc. So, preferably I would make the Claims type a generic `class GatewayClaim<T> where T:GatewayItem, new()` but then `List<GatewayClaim>` becomes invalid. And I don't weant to create a lot of derived classes just to support the various configurations that would be possible. I could use `List<GatewayClaimValue<GatewayItem>>` in GatewayItem which seems to work. But then I need to configure the DBSet and IEntityTypeConfiguration class for the various Claims tables and things become really messy by then.
So, I'm looking for an elegant solution to keep the amount of code to a minimum. And keep it readable!

---

To be clear: GatewayItem is NOT directly mapped to an entity, but a `public class GatewayItemConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : GatewayItem` is used to allow inheritance of basic configuration for any derived classes. This has an `public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)` method that gets overridden in the child configuration classes. Again, I'm trying to stay DRY in my code.
So the GatewayUser class uses a `public class GatewayUserConfiguration : GatewayItemConfiguration<GatewayUser> {}` class to configure the GatewayUser entity. I do the same way for a GatewayUserClaim which is derived from GatewayClaim at this moment. But the derived Claim types don't differ from their parent class, except the Items list is of a different type. Which is why I want to use `GatewayClient<T>` instead of `GatewayClient`.

Comment: Where did `GatewayClient` come from?  On the base class you could just have `public IEnumerable<GatewayClaim> Claims { get; }` and have the concrete classes implement that, in addition to having their specialized `GatewayUserClaims` etc.

Comment: In the model you show there's a one-to-many relationship, not many-to-many.

Comment: @GertArnold Correct. Fixed that. Originally, Claims also had multiple items but Claims has been split in 2 tables since: ClaimKeys and ClaimValues. I've kept Claims in the question, but they're claim values, and all claims (value) tables link to the same Claims key table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have several classes derived from GatewayItems: GatewayUser, GatewayCompany, GatewayRole

These are not closely-enough related to use inheritance in the database.  If you want to have a common base class in code, simply don't map GatewayItem to an EF entity.

> I want separate tables for each item/claim pair so I have UserItems/UserClaims

Great.  Just introduce a UserClaim type, again perhaps inheriting from an unmapped Claim type, and it will map to a separate UserClaim table.

Comment: Well, I edited my question to show that I'm already doing this. Well, more or less. There is NO GatewayItem entity in the database. Nor a GatewayClaim.